# Missing "getCustomizationId" in netsuite 2013.1?

Tags: php, netsuite

I'm using php toolkit for netsuite 2013.1. Here my code:

```
require_once("2013_1/NetSuiteService.php");

$service = new NetSuiteService();

$getCustomizationType = "itemCustomField";
$getCustomizationIdRq = new GetCustomizationIdRequest();
$getCustomizationIdRq->customizationType = new CustomizationType();
$getCustomizationIdRq->customizationType->getCustomizationTypeSpecified=true;
$getCustomizationIdRq->customizationType->getCustomizationType = GetCustomizationType::itemCustomField;

$getCustomizationIdResult = $service->getCustomizationId($getCustomizationIdRq, false);
```

And the result:
    No such operation 'getCustomizationId'

So I think this function is missing? Function [link](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10761#N1305602356-0)

Comment: This call still exists in the [2013_1 WSDL](https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2013_1_0/netsuite.wsdl) and the class definition for it still exists in the 2013 PHP Toolkit. However, there seems to be a bug in the PHP Toolkit that prevents this call from completing successfully. I was able to get this call to work using the ruby netsuite gem.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go...

```
$NSservice = new NetSuiteService();


$cT = new CustomizationType();  
$cT->getCustomizationType = "customRecordType";  // or itemCustomField or whatever

$gcIdR = new GetCustomizationIdRequest();
$gcIdR->customizationType = $cT;
$gcIdR->includeInactives = false;

$readResp = $NSservice->getCustomizationId($gcIdR);
print_r($readResp);
```